# For a $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ , if $|f(x)|\leq \exp(-\frac{1}{x^{2}})$ then is $f^{(n)}(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

Suppose $f\in C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$  . If $|f(x)|\leq \exp(-\frac{1}{x^{2}})$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0 $ . Does this imply $f^{(n)}(0)=0$
for all $n$ ?

I can see that $|\frac{f(h)}{h}|\leq \frac{1}{h}e^{\frac{-1}{h^{2}}}\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ which shows that $f'(0)=0$ .

But I am unsure about $n\geq 2$. Is it true for $n\geq 2$ ? If so, how can I prove this for $n\geq 2$?

I  tried to use Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem to see that $f'(ch)=\frac{f(h)}{h}$ for some $0<c<1$. But still, I cannot use this to get an approximation for all $f'(h)$ when $h$ is near $0$.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use induction and l'Hôpital.

- From you condition: $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h^n} = 0$$
- Using l'Hôpital:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h^n} = \frac1{n!} f^{(n)}(0)$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Ofcourse thanks! . Why didn't I think of L'Hospital.